# Передача json строки

Tags: php, jquery, json

Здравствуйте, необходимо передать json строку из одного файла php в другой. 
В первом файле прописала следующий код:

```
$json = array("item" => "dress", "id" => "353" );
echo json_encode($json);
```

Во втором файле пытаюсь поймать строку через JS и вывести ее в браузере при нажатии на кнопку:

```
<button id="showTableBtn">SHOW TABLE</button>
<div id="table"></div>
<script>
    $('#showTableBtn').click(function() {
        $.getJSON("file1.php",
            function(data){
                $("#table").html(data.item);
            });
    });
</script>
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не выводит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: В консоли какие ошибки?

Comment: В консоли ошибок нет

Comment: ошибки запроса? на вкладке сетевой активности, запрос возвращает то корректные данные?

Comment: в сетевой активности, запрос возвращает саму страницу, т.е. file1.php

Comment: дак у вас кроме данных двух строк в первом файле еще что-то есть?

Comment: @Yumie забыли написать `<?php` в начале файла?)

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov зачем `parseJSON` в `getJSON`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дак он же глянул, а не прочитал.

Comment: Извиняюсь за беспокойство. Переглянула файл, попробовала сделать иначе и заработало. Почему то после использования curl передача не хотела работать. Изначально файл брал html код с сайта, парсил его, получал данные и передавал их. Код упростила для примера.

Comment: Ошибся, бывает :)

Answer (score 1):

Все работает. Вы ж метод `getJSON` используете, а он относится к `jQuery` Подключил ее и все заработало. Для надежности указал в заголовках что формат данных JSON, но и без этого тоже сработало.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<boby>
<button id="showTableBtn">SHOW TABLE</button>
<div id="table"></div>
<script>
    $('#showTableBtn').click(function() {
        $.getJSON("file1.php",
            function(data){
                $("#table").html(data.item);
            });
    });
</script>
</boby>
</html>
```

ну и сам php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = array("item" => "dress", "id" => "353" );
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```